# How to sort a pandas dataframe on two (or more) different columns, in a particular order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

## Note

`df2` is the **only** thing that can be used here - using `df` or `df1` would be to use data that isn't possible. The data is received as `df2`, it wants to be manipulated to the form of `df1`. Neither `df1` or `df` can be used as part of of the solution (as `df1` **is** the solution).

---

## Setup test data

this is just setup for this post.

```py
# sample data
reps = {1: "dog", 2: "ant", 3: "cat", 6: "orange", 7: "apple", 8: "grape"}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"one": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], "two": [6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8]}
)
df = df.replace(reps).copy()
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=1).replace(reps).reset_index(drop=True)
```

## Problem

Sort `df1` so that it is in the same order as `df1`.

`df2`:

```
   one     two
0  cat   grape
1  dog   grape
2  cat  orange
3  cat   apple
4  dog   apple
5  dog  orange
6  ant   apple
7  ant  orange
8  ant   grape
```

`df1`

```
   one     two
0  dog  orange
1  dog   apple
2  dog   grape
3  ant  orange
4  ant   apple
5  ant   grape
6  cat  orange
7  cat   apple
8  cat   grape
```

### Conditions

You can not use `df1` as part of a solution, or `df`, the data is `df2`, and
it needs to be sorted into the ordering of `df1`.

## Attempt

I have tried with `pd.Categorical`, but couldn't make something work.

```py
order_one = ["dog", "ant", "cat"]
order_two = ["orange", "apple", "grape"]

df2 = (
    df2.groupby(["two"])
    .apply(lambda a: a.iloc[pd.Categorical(a["one"], order_one).argsort()])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

df2 = (
    df2.groupby(["one"])
    .apply(lambda a: a.iloc[pd.Categorical(a["two"], order_two).argsort()])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

## Edit

The solution should be based purely on `df2`, `df1` is just part of the test data and to demonstrate how `df2` should be sorted. A solution that uses `df1` is not viable as this is the result of sorting `df2`, I can't use that as part of a solution

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `pd.Categorical`

```
df2.one=pd.Categorical(df2.one,categories=df1.one.unique())
df2.two=pd.Categorical(df2.two,categories=df1.two.unique())
df2=df2.sort_values(['one','two'])
df2
   one     two
5  dog  orange
4  dog   apple
1  dog   grape
7  ant  orange
6  ant   apple
8  ant   grape
2  cat  orange
3  cat   apple
0  cat   grape
```

Make it into function

```
def yourfunc(x,y):
...     for c in x.columns : 
...         x[c]=pd.Categorical(x[c],categories=y[c].unique())
...     return x.sort_values(x.columns.tolist())
... 
yourfunc(df1,df2)
   one     two
8  cat   grape
6  cat  orange
7  cat   apple
2  dog   grape
0  dog  orange
1  dog   apple
5  ant   grape
3  ant  orange
4  ant   apple
```

Update

```
order_fruit = ["orange", "apple", "grape"]
order_animals = ["dog", "ant", "cat"]
def yourfunc(x,y):
...      for c, self in zip(x.columns,y) : 
...          x[c]=pd.Categorical(x[c],categories=self)
...      return x.sort_values(x.columns.tolist())
... 
yourfunc(df2,[order_animals,order_fruit])
   one     two
5  dog  orange
4  dog   apple
1  dog   grape
7  ant  orange
6  ant   apple
8  ant   grape
2  cat  orange
3  cat   apple
0  cat   grape
```

Comment: Sorry - `df1` here was purely test data, not to be seen. The data as seen would just be that of `df2`

Comment: @baxx how about input df ? use df replace df1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `input df`, here it should be assumed that `df2` is the data received, and that I want to manipulate this to the ordering of `df1`, I can't use `df1` to do that, as it's the result that I want. I do know the ordering that i want though (of course). I don't follow what you're saying with `input df` though

Comment: @baxx yourfunc(df,df2)

Comment: no, df2 is the *only* data that you can use, df, df1 are both just tests. I thought this was a lot more obvious than it seems to be so I will update the post, sorry

Comment: @baxx you get df2 from df , and you mentioned df can not be used ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215005/discussion-between-baxx-and-yoben-s).

Comment: @baxx please post here :-)

Comment: @baxx if you want to self-def sort , then you may need input the list one by one , there is no other solution

Comment: "if you want to self-def sort , then you may need input the list one by one , there is no other solution", this might be the case, I'm not sure :/

Comment: @baxx Base on my knowledge, it is hard to find a automatically way to achieve this type self-def sort . :-)

Comment: I realise that in my original attempt I used `df`, so it wasn't a solution, I'm sorry for any confusion because of that. If it needs to be custom that's ok with me, but I don't know how I can go about it really, at the moment

Comment: @baxx you may still need create the sorting order and pass them to category :-), just like what I did in the update

Comment: thanks i'll look, i just tried something with groupby, do you think it's an approach? actually i think I've done that wrong arghh

Comment: @baxx if done with groupby, the sort order will be by the default , may not as same as what you shown, for example, you would like display the order like 3,1,2 and groupby may display it 1,2,3

Comment: yeah... i had to do one then the other, grouping on the others column each time... it's ok for two perhaps, but idk how it would work for 3,4 etc

Comment: @baxx this is no need for groupby , when you apply the category with order , it equal to groupby apply the change to each sub-group

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are not sorting, since the order is not ascending or descending or alphabetical. You want to order df_2 with some user-specified ordering. You can do this by generating a numerical index based on your custom order, then sorting by that.

```
order_one = ["dog", "ant", "cat"]
order_two = ["orange", "apple", "grape"]

# Create dictionaries that define order
order_map_one = dict(zip(order_one, range(len(order_one))))
order_map_two = dict(zip(order_two, range(len(order_two))))

# Generate a temp column that maps numerical rank onto column values
df_2['order_one_rank'] = df['one'].map(order_map_one)
df_2['order_two_rank'] = df['two'].map(order_map_two)

# Sort by these temp columns
df_2.sort_values(['order_one_rank', 'order_two_rank'], inplace=True)

# Then delete the temp columns to recover the original df_2
df_2.drop('order_one_rank', 1, inplace=True)
df_2.drop('order_two_rank', 1, inplace=True)
```

That should leave df_2 in the order you are looking for.